# insert is made in the last open textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Lets see if i can make my self understandable .

this creates multiple menus and it gets the values to populate it on a txt, the issue here is that it always assume the last request_box textbox, if i click on option 1 he will populate the last request_box that is inside option3

this call is made like this

```
 makesubmenu("something",tab1)
 makesubmenu("something1",tab2)
 makesubmenu("something2",tab3)
```

.

```
def makesubmenu(tipo_de_conf, framename):
    frmbut = ttk.Frame(framename)
    frmbut.pack(side="top", anchor='nw')

    global lsttiporeq, lsttitreq, lstjsonreq, lstexpectresq, request_box

    varconfbook = open("menu_dumps.txt", "r").readlines()
    lsttiporeq = []
    lsttitreq = []
    lstjsonreq = []
    lstexpectresq = []
    cont = 0

    for line in varconfbook:
        if tipo_de_conf in line:
            tiporeq, titreq, jsonreq, expectresq = line.split('<->')
            lsttiporeq.append(tiporeq)
            lsttitreq.append(titreq)
            lstjsonreq.append(jsonreq)
            lstexpectresq.append(expectresq)

            ttk.Button(frmbut, width="20", text=titreq, command=lambda cont=cont: ChangConfWI(int(cont))).grid(column=0, row=cont, padx=10, pady=10)
        cont += 1

    frmtxtb2 = ttk.Frame(framename)
    frmtxtb2.pack(side="right", anchor='ne')

    ttk.Label(frmtxtb2, text="Response:").grid(column=4, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    request_box = ScrolledText(frmtxtb2, width=75, height=10, wrap=tk.WORD)
    request_box.grid(column=4, row=2, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=35)

    return lsttiporeq, lsttitreq, lstjsonreq, lstexpectresq, request_box


def ChangConfWI(tipreq):
        global expResp, payload, headers, timeoutvar, tiporeq
        payload = lstjsonreq[tipreq]
        request_box.delete('1.0', END)
        request_box.insert(tk.INSERT, payload)
        return expResp, payload, headers, timeoutvar, tiporeq,request_box
```

txt example:

```
something  <-> without inputs <->  {} <->   Response retrieving no
something1  <-> inputs <->  {} <->   Response retrieving 
something1  <-> without inputs <->  {} <->   Response retrieving no 
something2  <-> inputs <->  {} <->   Response retrieving 
something2  <-> without inputs <->  {} <->   Response retrieving no
```

I need it to make the insert in its specific option.

thanks

Comment: You know that your code only keeps a reference to the last `request_box` object. So when you call `ChangConfWI` and it calls `request_box.insert(...)`, it only happens in the last `request_box` text box

Comment: @TheLizzard i know that, what i was woundering was how can i fix it? otherwise i will have to create a request_box for each option :s maybe add something like request_box+number with a counter to add +1, any ideas?

Comment: Try passing in `lstjsonreq`, and `request_box` when calling `ChangConfWI`. I would recommend that you look into classes and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, the best solution is to use a class to represent each tab, so that the class instance can hold a reference to its text widget.

Since you aren't using classes, you can pass the text widget to your `ChangeConWI` function. That requires that you make the widget before you create the buttons.

```
def makesubmenu(tipo_de_conf, framename):
    ...
    request_box = ScrolledText(frmtxtb2, width=75, height=10, wrap=tk.WORD)
    for line in varconfbook:
        if tipo_de_conf in line:
            ...
            ttk.Button(..., command=lambda cont=cont text=request_box: ChangConfWI(text, cont))
...
def ChangConfWI(text, tipreq):
    ...
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    text.insert(tk.INSERT, payload)
```

Comment: OP's code will have other problems unless you also pass in the `lstjsonreq` variable.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yeah, but they were specifically asking about how to reference the text widget. This answer addresses that question.

Comment: Adding it as a note at the end, would have helped OP with their future problem and wouldn't have been faster than the reply to my comment :D

Comment: @TheLizzard: feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: Thank you so much guys :) about the lstjsonreq should i pass it here ChangConfWI(text, cont, lstjsonreq) right?

Comment: this is not working, maybe its better if i learn classes, can someone give an example of how to do this with a class? thanks